# Use 32bit DLLs with 64bit Lazarus compiler

Tags: dll, import, 32bit-64bit, lazarus

The problem happens when I try to static load 32bit DLL which is written using Visual C++ from 64bit version of Lazarus compiler. The function call always fail with following run-time error:

> The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b). Click OK
>   to close the application.

I try same project on 32bit version of Lazarus compiler it and works without any issues.

Is it not possible to load 32bit version of DLL with 64bit version of Lazarus compiler or am I need to change some setting(s) in the Lazarus compiler?

This is console application project and I declare my function import like this:

```
function TestFunction(Param1: Word; Param2 : Word) : Byte; stdcall; external 'test.dll';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it is not possible. 32-bit EXE loads 32-bit DLL, 64-bit EXE loads 64-bit DLL.